# Installing Faucet in a Box Cryptocurrency Script to Wordpress Website

Tags: wordpress, file-upload, cpanel

I'm a fairly amateur coder/programmer, hopefully you all can forgive me in advance if my questions do not make sense.

So I downloaded Faucet in a Box script. I then opened and modified the Config.php file to contain my own information. I also installed a new database on my SiteGround hosted server.

My stupid question that I cannot for the life of me find the answer to... Where do I upload the script/zip file now?

I have accessed file manager in cPanel, and uploaded the zip, but was not sure where I unpack and leave it?